# Best practice to track web APIs

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, api, iis

Currently I'm using **MVC attribute** with custom code to track **REST APIs details** - such as **userIP, requestURL, userIdentity, browser details, query parameters and etc.**

But this is not the best practice to use web API tracking concept because it is running synchronously and holding the main thread execution so it is hampering the performance...

Also don't want to use tracking logic in the background thread because it consumes the memory.

Please help me to get the best practice to track web API details.

Answer (score 0):

Use of `ActionFilterAttribute` along with `Task` without `await` will not block caller.

```
public class TrackAPIAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var details = GetDetails(actionContext);

        Task.Run(() => TrackDetails(details));  //No await
    }

    ...
    ...
}
```